# How to set one of the predefined layout patterns just for one agent type? (preferably by code)

Tags: anylogic

I plan to use two types of agents in my simulation.

For one agent type I plan to use set the position explicitly by the setXYZ() method called in the "On startup" action of that agent type.

Fort the second agent type I plan to use one of the predefined layout patterns (random or ring) as described in:

https://help.anylogic.com/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.anylogic.help%2Fhtml%2Fagentbased%2FContinuous_Layouts.html

The problem is the following code placed in in the "On startup" action of the Main agent type doesn't differentiante between my two agent types (and places all the agents in a circle e.g.):

```
setLayoutType(Agent.LAYOUT_RING); 
applyLayout();
```

Shall I somehow modify the code above  (as I've tried already) or is there another way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the layout type has to be the same for all agents present in the space... nevertheless... you can do this:

```
//first you apply the ring layout to everything
setLayoutType(Agent.LAYOUT_RING); 
applyLayout();
//then you define the type of agent you don't want to follow the ring layout separately
for(int i=0;i<100;i++){//assuming you will create 100 agents initially
    MyAgent p=add_myAgents();//you need to create your agents after the ring layout is applied though..
    p.setXY(uniform(0,500), uniform(0,500));//assuming your agents are in a 500x500 square in main
}
```

I don't know if there is a better way... but this is what I know is possible

Comment: the problem is those agents to be placed in a predefined layout aren't supposed to be created/added before those placed by the setXYZ() method as they they derive their orientation from them (they are facing towards them)

Comment: There may be some workarounds that would let me use this solution, but in the end they don't seem to be worth the complications. I shall probably devise all the positions by code and don't depend on the layouts.

I will accept the answer as it seems as the best possible solution for my answer as it was originally stated. Thank you Felipe